# How to use a Bluetooth-controlled relay to simulate a button press on a garage door remote?

Tags: relay

As a DIY project, I'd like to use this keypad (Danapad by Danalock) to open my garage door. The keypad communicates via Bluetooth with a "universal module" that's designed to open gates, magnetic locks, etc. I've read the manual, but don't know enough about electronics to know how to make my idea work: With the correct PIN, I'd like the relay to simulate a button press on the spare remote control that came with my garage door opener. (The communication between the keypad and module is handled by the product -- nothing for me to do there.)

Here's a link to the specs on the universal module: https://www.andivi.com/danalock-universal-module-v3/

My questions:

- The module has 2 relays (one normally open and one normally closed). How can I use one of these relays to simulate a press on the garage remote?
- The remote is battery-powered so it doesn't need power. I do need to power the module. I'm thinking I can just find a 12 V power supply for it and attach the module + remote to a circuit board. Am I oversimplifying or is there anything else I need to consider?

I've attached an example wiring diagram from the manual for a door strike.
[image: door strike wiring diagram]

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: `one normally open and one normally closed` ... are you certain that is two relays?

Comment: @jsotola According to the specifications there's two relays each with NC and NO

Answer (score 0):

The module contains two relays, each having normally open and normally closed pins.

If you want to do it the simple way, you can disassemble your garage remote and solder wires to the buttons, then connect them to the normally open pins of one of the relays. (I actually did this soldering thing to my garage remote, it's not super pretty but it's been working for a few years)

As long as you can verify that the designed input voltage of the module is indeed 12 volts and you can be sure that the 12V supply is good, I don't see any issues with it.

Comment: Thanks @syntax. I will double-check the power requirements. In a wiring diagram from the manual I just attached (see above), they seem to suggest wiring the power output to the common for the relay, if I read it correctly. What does that do?